# Can't get cloud zoom to work on woocommerce site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, zooming

Working on a wordpress website, custom theme, using woocommerce. Use a swatches plugin to show images for attribute variants, also we have the professor cloudzoom installed that we were wanting to zoom on the swatch image. Seen this done on other websites using same set up, However struggling to get it to work but there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the script.

This is what we are working on

http://www.juliajones.co.uk/shop/arm-chairs/sits-ginevra-arm-chair/

This was how i was trying to get it to look like

http://www.stocktons.co.uk/product/armchairs/sits-ginevra-armchair/

If anyone could point me in the right direction i would be very greatful. Overlooking something but not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the class 'cloudzoom' to the image.